# How to get user belongs to which group in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have 350 groups in in my sites collection. I need to find a user by passing login name get his groups belongs to? How to get programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [SPWeb.AllUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allusers.aspx) collection to get the `SPUser` by login name (alternatively use [SPWeb.EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) if you don't know if they have been added yet)
2. Use [SPUser.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.groups.aspx) to get the groups the user is a member of

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this excellent post on ASP.NET forums:

[C# Example: How to get all groups, users and roles from SharePoint using SPGroup, SPUser, SPRole ...](http://forums.asp.net/p/1012092/1353022.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

CheckOut this one

SPFieldUserValue usersField = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web);
 bool isUser = SPUtility.IsLoginValid(SPContext.Current.Site, usersField.User.LoginName);
 SPGroup group = SPContext.Current.Web.Groups.GetByID(usersField.LookupId);